# How can I select and change COM port using XML file on my c# application?

Tags: c#, xml, debugging, com-port

I have a c# windows application that uses the available debug board COM port to run.

I want to create a settings.xml file so the COM port is picked by the application using xml file instead of using hard coded COM port number (example: string command = "command filename.py... COM16 ...command").

Comment: The most straightforward way is to simply create a `settings.xml` and a class with the same structure, then on the startup just read it, deserialize it and use data from that class.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific. Do you have problems creating a settings file or initializing a given COM port?

Comment: initializing com port and how to specify xml in my c# code

Answer (score 0):

Create your `settings.xml`. For example, it has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<COMSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Port>COM16</Port>
</COMSettings>
```

Create the class to deserialize your xml into it:

```
public class COMSettings
{
    public string Port { get; set; };

    // some other data if needed
 
    public COMSettings() { }
    public COMSettings(string port)
    {
        Port = port;
    }
}
```

The usage is simple - read and deserialize xml and then just use your port value.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

...

// somewhere in your app
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(COMSettings));

using (var fs = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

var settings = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fs) as COMSettings;

// usage
var command = $"command filename.py {settings.Port}";
```

Comment: ChatGPT generated content is forbidden on Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks. what's fs?

Comment: @DavidG I have no idea why you think it was generated by chatgpt or smth

Comment: @PBstack `fs` is a `FileStream` (it is initialized after `XmlSerializer` in my example):

`using (var fs = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));`